# Dictionary for eh, uh-huh, eww and so on

Tags: formality

I'm looking for a dictionary or good reference for words such as *eh*,  *uh-huh*, or *eww*.
I'm not an English major, so I don't really know what should I search for (not to mention tags).
I've seen some questions regarding particular ones, though couldn't find all of them listed in one place.

Such words appear to be quite common among native speakers.
Maybe there's a place with such words gathered together and explained?
Usually they are not explained in standard dictionaries - a more or less complete list with explanations would be much appreciated, perhaps not only for me.

Comment: *they are not explained in standard dictionaries* -- I just Googled all three and they came up with reasonable definitions.  (Be sure type something like `define eww`.)

Comment: And there's [this](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/topics/language/sounds-used-as-interjections/).

Comment: What he wants is a word that means "eh", "uh-huh", "eww" and etc, I think.

Comment: Is looking for or assisting with book picks on topic in ELU?

Comment: @Ibf No, requests for resources are off-topic for EL&U. However, the community has put together [some links to useful resources](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available).

Comment: You are missing the word interjections.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because requests for resources are off-topic on EL&U.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those words are interjections. An interjection is a word or group of words that expresses emotion. They can show happiness, surprise, anger, impatience, etc. They can also be used to get attention. Interjections do not have a grammatical purpose in the sentence. They are considered parenthetical and are set off with commas.

[Interjections](http://www.englishmirror.com/english-grammar/uses-of-interjection-3.html)

[Interjections](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/100-mostly-small-but-expressive-interjections/)

[Interjections](https://www.englishgrammar101.com/module-7/conjunctions-and-interjections/lesson-8/interjections)

Comment: Also, there is no standard spelling for interjections. They lend themselves to odd spellings and exclamation points. And they aren't defined in dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for *Onomatopoeia*, according to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/onomatopoeia) they are:

> the act of creating or using words that include sounds that are similar to the noises the words refer to

As opposed to what some have said, many of them are listed in the dictionary:

> **eww** [Cambridge Dictionary:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/eww) *used to express surprise or confusion, to ask someone to repeat what they have said, or as a way of getting someone to give some type of reaction to a statement that you have made*
>
> **eh** [Cambridge Dictionary:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/eh) *used to express surprise or confusion, to ask someone to repeat what they have said, or as a way of getting someone to give some type of reaction to a statement that you have made*
>
> **uh-huh** [Cambridge Dictionary:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/uh-huh) *used in writing to represent the sound that people sometimes make in order to agree with or show understanding of something that has just been said*

You can find many (more) of them on a website call [written sound](http://www.writtensound.com/index.php). (although *eww* wasn't listed on the site, or maybe it's listed under a slightly different name).

Attribution:

(Definition of “onomatopoeia” from the Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary & Thesaurus © Cambridge University Press)

(Definition of “eww” from the Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary & Thesaurus © Cambridge University Press)

(Definition of “eh” from the Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary & Thesaurus © Cambridge University Press)

(Definition of “uh-huh” from the Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary & Thesaurus © Cambridge University Press)

Comment: The examples given in the question aren’t onomatopoeia. _Tweet_, _arf_, _plonk_, _swish_, _drrrrrring_, _bzzzzz_, _whoosh_, _badump-tsh_ etc.—those are onomatopoeia, words (or ‘words’) that make use of our speech organs to attempt to recreate sounds found around us. _Eww_, _eh_, and _uh-huh_ don’t mimick anything, they’re just meaningless sounds that happen to have taken on a specific set of meanings in English.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I would argue that some of those sounds are not language specific. Particularly the *eww*, sometimes used for expressing disgust, is an emotion referenced as part of the [evolution of morality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolution_of_morality#Emotion) (in humans, before English was around). I wouldn't even be surprised if other animals express disgust too. They might even have a similar sound for it (I'm thinking of monkeys here).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet also the CD definition for *uh-huh* specifically says **to represent the sound that people sometimes make [...]**. So that, too, would be *onomatopoeia*, right?

Comment: No, that just means that the spelling _uh-huh_ is used as the written representation of what is orally /əˈhə/, in the same way that _chair_ is used in writing to represent the sound that people make when talking about chairs. Onomatopoeia in general is somewhat language-agnostic: if you say _whoosh_, people everywhere will know it’s the sound of something flying through the air. The three given here, conversely, are quite specific to English, including _eww_. The same sound in Welsh means ‘to/for his/her/its/their X’. _Eh_ in Portuguese means ‘right!’; in Greek, ‘come on!’.

Comment: Of course, all languages use sounds to express disgust, confusion, etc., but that doesn’t make them onomatopoeia. Onomatopoeia is specifically hearing something in the world around us, and then mimicking the sound made by that something and using the resulting sound as a word somehow relating to that thing. The _eww_ words are [ideophones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideophone), and onomatopoeia is a subset of ideophony, but they are not the same. It all falls under the broad category of sound symbolism, but in different ways.

Comment: It is my understanding that *eh* or very similar sounds are used in many languages. To support that, consider the [list of fillers on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filler_(linguistics)#Filler_words_in_different_languages). Having seen your second comment, *ideophones* might fit even better, feel free to submit that as a separate answer. :)

Comment: Yes, such sounds are quite common in many languages, but not because they’re mimicking something—it’s just because they’re quick, neutral sounds, essentially what comes out if we just open our mouths and engage the vocal chords.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet fair point. I'll leave the answer as it is (even though I agree that it's not the best answer). Please leave your comments, I think they are very helpful in illustrating when something is or isn't onomatopoeia. :)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I agree with all your points except the (irrelevant to this question) "Onomatopoeia in general is somewhat language-agnostic". O9ia, despite it feeling non-linguistic, is notoriously language specific. For example, it seems that [every language has their own way to represent a dog barking](https://www.quora.com/What-are-all-the-different-onomatopoeic-words-for-dog-barks-used-by-different-languages).

Comment: As to the OP, tangentially, there seems to be [only one ew/uh-huh/eww style universal, and that is the question 'hunh?'](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/science-nature/everybody-almost-every-language-says-huh-huh-180949822/)

Comment: Note that the many articles talking about 'hunh' refer to it commonly as a 'word'. I disagree with this label, but I acquiesce to journalists oversimplifying things for a general audience.

Comment: @Mitch you might be interested in [this study](http://www.pnas.org/content/early/2016/09/06/1605782113) analysing many languages and showing so-called *sound-meaning association biases* across them. They also say: *"reveals that unrelated languages very often use (or avoid) the same sounds for specific referents"*, so it's not just that the words are etymologically related.

Comment: @Mitch Hence why I only said _somewhat_ language-agnostic. There are many differences, but there are also more commonalities within onomatopoeia than elsewhere‑more specifically, even though many languages have differing ways of representing the same thing onomatopoically, foreign onomatopoeia is frequently _understandable_, precisely because they mimic familiar real-world sounds. This differs from many other types of ideophones, which are so language-dependent that they are not understandable by speakers of other languages at all. As an anecdotal example, I used to live in a flat with a →

Comment: → German girl and a Chinese guy. The German girl and I would speak in English (which the Chinese guy didn’t speak), and we would frequently use the familiar [encouraging _mhm_](http://sciencenordic.com/mhm-and-other-sounds-help-conversations) when talking to each other (meaning ‘I hear you, go on’ and uttered with a rising intonation). After a while, the Chinese guy noticed this, but he couldn’t understand it. He thought it was a question, akin to “Huh?” or “What’s that?”, but couldn’t understand why we kept mishearing or doubting each other all the time. It was completely language-dependent.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Wikitionary can explain why the Chinese person might have misunderstood. [The sound (嗯) has different pronunciations with different meanings in Chinese](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%97%AF): *express doubt or curiosity*, *express surprise* and *express agreement or pledge*. Perhaps you meant the latter interjection but it sounded to the Chinese person as the first or second.

Comment: @JJJ That’s part of it—the encouraging sense of 嗯 is pronounced with a falling tone (unlike the English encouragement, which has rising intonation). It’s also monosyllabic, whereas the English one is disyllabic. Another part is that 嗯 alone is used much less frequently in Mandarin than _mhm_ in English; it’s commonly used along with (or in turns with) 对 _duì_ ‘correct’ in natural speech.

Comment: Must be bring other language into this?? Please. Interjections are onomatopoeia but not all onomatopoeia are interjections.

Comment: lambie, what sound does 'ewww' imitate? An onomatopoeia is a word that phonetically imitates, resembles or suggests the sound that it describes. As an uncountable noun, onomatopoeia refers to the property of such words. Common occurrences of onomatopoeia include animal noises such as "oink", "miaow" (or "meow"), "roar" and "chirp".